# Left click is returning different originSource than right click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid
PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="BookGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp"             
PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="BookGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp">....</DataGrid>
```

(The datagrid is default datagrid with automatically generated columns)

Code behind:

```
   private void BookGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource);
   }
```

When I left click with my mouse on a column's header for example, the debug prints out this:

System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader: Category

But when I click with my right mouse on the same spot:

System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock

Same thing when I try to click on a form button, left click "System.Windows.Controls.Button: Edit",
right click "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock".

How is that possible?
Both clicks should be returning the same thing.

I am not using any custom code for handling the mouse on anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me clear few things before moving onto the actual behaviour you are experiencing.

MouseDown and MouseUp are coupled events i.e. they work in conjunction. ***First mouseDown button is raised and then MouseUp event is raised.***

---

Also, there is difference between PreviewMouseUp and MouseUp. ***PreviewMouseUp is tunnelling event*** which travel from root to the originator of the event whereas ***MouseUp is bubbling event*** which bubbles from its originator to the root.

---

The behaviour you are experiencing is correct one. Let's understand that step by step for sample when you click on dataGridColumnHeader:

1. PreviewMouseDown event is raised with OriginalSource set to TextBlock which travels from window to the TextBlock.
2. Then MouseDown event is raised which will travel from TextBlock to Window unless it is handled by some UIElement in between *(i.e. by setting e.Handled to true)*. And ***DataGridColumnHeader does handle the event to sort column.*** Thus, it won't travel up to the Window.
3. Now, corresponding ***PreviewMouseUp event will be raised whose Original Source will be set as to the control which handled the MouseDown event*** which in your case is DataGridColumnHeader. Hence, you see DataGridColumnHeader in console.

You see, OriginalSource as TextBlock on right click because ***right click is not handled by DataGridColumnHeader to sort columns. Hence, it travels perfectly too and fro from root window to originator TextBlock.***

Same goes for Button which handles left mouse down event in Click event.

---

So, if instead of using PreviewMouseRightButtonUp and PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, you ***use PreviewMouseRightButtonDown and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, you will see original source will be same in both cases*** which will be TextBlock because MouseDown event is handled and not PreviewMouseDown.

```
<DataGrid
PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="BookGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp"             
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="BookGrid_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp">....</DataGrid>
```

I would suggest you to read more about these events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx).